# Error handling in package using a filter but missing reference

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a package that can handle errors from methods by simply adding a `[Attribute]` above the method.

In my package I have

```
public class RequestLogFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
     Log(filterContext.Exception);

     base.OnException(filterContext);
  }

  private void Log(Exception exception)
  {
     //log exception here..

  }
}
```

When I try to use it in my MVC project

```
[RequestLogFilter]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
```

It says that `Cannot access internal class here`.  My question is, is there some other decorator I should use besides `ExceptionFilterAttribute`?  It says I need to reference System.Web.Http, but I don't have that in the references selection in my MVC project.

The goal is that if they call this type of filter It will log any exception to said filter.

Comment: Try by adding System.Web as reference.

Comment: Did you reference the right `ExceptionFilterAttribute`? The [OnException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.exceptionfilterattribute.onexception?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ExceptionFilterAttribute_OnException_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ExceptionContext_) signature is different.

Comment: I referenced `using System.Web.Http.Filters;`

Answer (score 0):

In MVC project you should use this one

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
```

in WebAPI project

```
 public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
```

Comment: I'm doing the override in a class library.  When I do the `ExceptionContext` it tells me that there is no override.  and my `base.OnException(filterContext);` will no longer work.  if its even required?

Comment: @TheDizzle in this case you need to add `System.Web.Mvc.dll` to your package

Comment: I dont see that as an option when i add reference